# Animation starts only when I touch the screen

Tags: android, list, animation

I have a listview with entries which have a fade out animation when the user deletes\edits an entry in the list.

For some reason, after I perform the action (edit\delete) the animation will not start until I press the screen again. Only they will the animation actually perform.

From this method the animation is being called:

```
public void replace(View view, long position) {
    int hoursSum = 0;
    int minuteSum = 0;
    boolean hoursIssue = false;

    if (finsihIntMinutes >= startIntMinutes) {
        minuteSum = finsihIntMinutes - startIntMinutes;

    } else if (finsihIntMinutes < startIntMinutes) {
        minuteSum = (finsihIntMinutes + Utility.MINUTES_TIME_UNIT)
                - startIntMinutes;
        hoursIssue = true;
    }

    if (finishIntHours >= startIntHours) {
        hoursSum = finishIntHours - startIntHours;
        if (hoursIssue == true) {
            --hoursSum;
        }
    } else if (finishIntHours < startIntHours) {

        hoursSum = (finishIntHours + Utility.HOURS_TIME_UNIT)
                - startIntHours;
    }

    double salper = (minuteSum * Main.sal) / 60;
    double salper2 = hoursSum * (Main.sal);
    String madeSoFar = ""
            + String.valueOf(formatter.format(salper2 + salper));
    String edited = "**Edited**";

    String totalTime = "" + hoursSum + ":" + minuteSum;

    DB.edit(position, Shifts.editDate, Shifts.editStartTime,
            Shifts.editEndTime, Shifts.dayString, totalTime, minuteSum,
            madeSoFar, edited, totalHours, totalMinutes);

    moneySummary = getMoney();
    hoursSummary = "Total Hours: " + getHours();
    summary.setText(moneySummary);

    **FastScrollAdapter.animate(Shifts.view);**

}
```

Here is the animation code:

```
public static void animate(final View v) {

    Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    out.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    out.setDuration(350);
    v.setAnimation(out);
    out.start();
    out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.i("Animation", "Started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            // Shifts.setSummaryCursor.requery();
            Shifts.getMoneyCursor.requery();
            FastScrollAdapter.cursor.requery();
            Shifts.CA.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            // Shifts.setSummaryCursor.requery();
            Shifts.getMoneyCursor.requery();
            FastScrollAdapter.cursor.requery();
            Shifts.CA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("Animation", "Ended");

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I've just realized that it works great when testing on android 2.3.X devices, just not on ICS. Probably I'm doing something wrong with the api?

Comment: hi, did you get a solution to this one?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem, I solved it by calling

```
view.clearAnimation();
```

just before

```
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the order

```
1. v.setAnimation(out);
2. out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()); 
3. v.startAnimation(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: the animation was not performet in the UE thread. Try to run the animation posting it in the UE thead:

```
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    yourView.startAnimation(yourAnimation));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please see my comment in my post above - it works fine on android 2.3.X and so. Just not on ICS. These are the only one's I've checked on but it must be something with the API.

Comment: Have you tried anyway the solution I suggested? Maybe on 2.3.X works because an invalidation or something else is triggered after you start the animation and that's not happening in ICS. I'd try to run it n the UE thread to test the result.
My solution is working in ICS and Jelly Beans for me.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried doing it with an handler and it still didn't work